Не получается скачать файл с Mega
Я пытался скачать файл из Mega используя библиотеку mega, но все безуспешно
public_exported_web_link = m.export('myfile.doc')
public_exported_web_link = m.export('my_mega_folder/my_sub_folder_to_share')

file = m.find('myfile.doc')
m.download(file)
m.download_url('https://mega.co.nz/#!utYjgSTQ!OM4U3V5v_W4N5edSo0wolg1D5H0fwSrLD3oLnLuS9pc')
m.download(file, '/home/john-smith/Desktop')
# specify optional download filename (download_url() supports this also)
m.download(file, '/home/john-smith/Desktop', 'myfile.zip')

Выводятся разные ошибки. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать. Отправьте коды, я попробую запустить и покажу, если будут ошибки.

Очевидно, изучать выводящиеся ошибки

Проверить для начала скачивается ли такой файл вообще стандартным способом. Огрызок кода в данном случае не оставляет возможности найти ошибки.

"Выводятся разные ошибки." - эти ошибки должны быть показаны прямо в вопросе. Текстом. И код должен быть воспроизводимым - с импортом библиотек и т.д. Только логины/пароли/токены нужно убрать, остальной код лучше весь приводить, нужный для его запуска.

Есть описание этой технологии, но я не тестировал (нет там файлов и не очень-то хочется инсталлировать ненужный мне модуль). Вижу существенные отличия предлагаемого кода от Вашего. Есть два варианта.
Первый вариант:
from mega import Mega

# Создаем экземпляр Mega
mega = Mega()

# Входим в аккаунт Mega
m = mega.login('your_email@example.com', 'your_password')

# Находим файл по его имени
file = m.find('filename.ext')

# Загружаем файл
m.download(file)

И второй вариант:
from mega import Mega

# Создаем экземпляр Mega
mega = Mega()

# Входим в аккаунт Mega
m = mega.login('your_email@example.com', 'your_password')

# Загружаем файл по публичной ссылке
m.download_url('https://mega.co.nz/#!utYjgSTQ!OM4U3V5v_W4N5edSo0wolg1D5H0fwSrLD3oLnLuS9pc')

